# how to enable a input field (th:field) and set a value(th:value) at the same time

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Prescription

I want to put ${#authentication.name}in  the input field  and save in *{pres} location in my database . Is it possible?

If anyone is interested, solved this issue using following structure

Comment: If anyone is interested, solved this issue using following structure
 <input th:value="${#authentication.name}" type="hidden" th:attr="name='pres'" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feld `pres` should be initialized before the form is rendered.

```
// In the controller
formObject.setPres(/* however you get authentication.name in the controller */);
```

Then your input will be initialized to the correct value when you use `th:field`.

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{pres}" />
```

Comment: Thank You 
but 
<input th:value="${#authentication.name}" type="hidden" th:attr="name='pres'" />
worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this method.

Instead of using th:field use html id & name. Set value using th:value

```html
<input type="text" id="pres" name="pres" 
       th:value="${#authentication.name}" />
```

The `pres` field was introduced as `object.pres`.

Comment: Thank You but <input th:value="${#authentication.name}" type="hidden" th:attr="name='pres'" /> worked for me